# In CXF, is there a way to program the configuration of a client programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I have a project that contains web services and also a web service client.  I want to configure the web service client without effecting the web services.  How can I do this?

I want to configure this client so that it can set these values: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/TLS+Configuration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, spring config is purely optional and in the end it is mainly translated into "java classes and cofigurations." Usually the [CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html) offer both spring and programmatic configuration, and in your case there is this special paragraph which should give you a starting point:

> Please see [this blog](http://aruld.info/programming-ssl-for-jetty-based-cxf-services/) entry on how the HTTPConduit TLS properties
>   can be set up from the code

Since URL only answers are usually discouraged, I'm going to "spam" this answer copy-pasting the entire client code for whoever might need it:

```
  public class Client {
       private static void configureSSLOnTheClient(Object c) {
          org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(c);
          HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

          try {
              TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
              tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);

              KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
              String trustpass = "password";

              File truststore = new File("certs\\truststore.jks");
              keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
              TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
              trustFactory.init(keyStore);
              TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
              tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);

              truststore = new File("certs\\wibble.jks");
              keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());
              KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
              keyFactory.init(keyStore, trustpass.toCharArray());
              KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
              tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km);

              FiltersType filter = new FiltersType();
              filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT_.*");
              filter.getInclude().add(".*_EXPORT1024_.*");
              filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_DES_.*");
              filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_NULL_.*");
              filter.getExclude().add(".*_DH_anon_.*");
              tlsParams.setCipherSuitesFilter(filter);

              httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
          } catch (KeyStoreException kse) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + kse.getCause());
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + nsa.getCause());
          } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + fnfe.getCause());
          } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException uke) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + uke.getCause());
          } catch (CertificateException ce) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + ce.getCause());
          } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + gse.getCause());
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
              System.out.println("Security configuration failed with the following: " + ioe.getCause());
          }
      }

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          System.out.println("The client's security configuration will be done programatically.");
          System.out.println();
          String address = "https://localhost:9001/SoapContext/SoapPort";
          JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
          proxyFactory.setServiceClass(Greeter.class);
          proxyFactory.setAddress(address);

          Greeter client = (Greeter) proxyFactory.create();
          configureSSLOnTheClient(client);

          System.out.println("Invoking greetMe...");
          try {
              String resp = client.greetMe(System.getProperty("user.name"));
              System.out.println("Server responded with: " + resp);
              System.out.println();

          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Invocation failed with the following: " + e.getCause());
              System.out.println();
          }

      }
  }
```

Comment: The problem is my code is in a war and doesn't have a `main`.  My code is a `javax.xml.ws.Service` and the client call is made by getting the port from that.  The port is an instance of [this](http://imgur.com/Q5jRuPd). I'm not really sure how to get the `Client` out of that

Comment: Actually it seems I can say `ClientProxy.getClient(port)`.  I'll let you know how that works